# ValueError: read of closed file when reading SAS table with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sas, valueerror

As a premise, I am new to SAS.
I have a SAS dataset stored on a server. I downloaded it on my pc by doing:

> Tasks > Data > Download data files to PC.

Now I am trying to read it in Python. When running

```
df = pd.read_sas('name.sas7bdat')
```

I get Value Error read of the closed file. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you close file in  EG or SAS Base program?

Comment: SAS Enterprise guide. I must clarify I didn't create the dataset myself or have access to any script in SAS

Comment: I want to say, that EG can lock table. You can check PID of process that lock file in Monitoring panel of Windows (I Don't remember right name )

Comment: @SanekZhitnik Resource monitor?

Comment: Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc).

Comment: @SanekZhitnik I'm sorry, could you clarify what you mean by PID of process?

Comment: I'm running SAS on Citrix Engine (I'm connected to the server of a company). How do I check where EG is locking tables and how do I prevent that?

Comment: can you add more information about how (by which program) you download file? without context about problem we can talk in comments all day =)